# Is is possible to automatically sync Firefox bookmark updates with an HTML file?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, bookmarks

I bookmark a lot of pages everyday and I export them as well into an HTML file. The thing is whenever is bookmark a page **can it automatically get updated or synced with the HTML file**?

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and Firefox 30.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox bookmarks are stored in the places.sqlite database in your profile folder. It looks like they're split across the moz_bookmarks and moz_places tables.  You'd have to write a script to join the data and write it to HTML.

My Windows Firefox 30 install has a bookmarkbackups directory in my profile. It has bookmarks in JSON format